# what is the equivalent "az ad sp create-for-rbac" in powershell az

Tags: azure-powershell

What is the equivalent of az command in powershell

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --query "{ client_id: appId, client_secret: password, tenant_id: tenant }"
```

What extra parameters should I add to `New-AzADServicePrincipal`

> **az ad sp create-for-rbac**  Create a service principal and configure its
>   access to Azure resources.

I would like to do the same with powershell az command

Comment: So you want to specify a client secret for service principal?

Comment: @StanleyGong Please see above. The az command creates a service principal and configure access to azure resource.

Comment: Yes, I know that , I just not sure what is your end requirement . If you just want to know how to use New-AzADServicePrincipal command . This official reference will be helpful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-3.0.0

Comment: yes output should have client id, client secret and tenant id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create an Azure AD service principle by command : `New-AzADServicePrincipal` and get its client id, client secret and tenant id as cli command replies , try command below :

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal 
$clientsec = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("", $sp.Secret).Password
$tenantID = (get-aztenant).Id
$jsonresp = 
@{client_id=$sp.ApplicationId 
    client_secret=$clientsec
    tenant_id=$tenantID}
$jsonresp | ConvertTo-Json
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: What is the difference az ad sp create Create a service principal.
az ad sp create-for-rbac Create a service principal and configure its access to Azure resources. The way I see it az ad sp create =New-AzADServicePrincipal what is az ad sp create-for-rbac = ?

Comment: Hi @kumar , that az ad sp create = New-AzADServicePrincipal -Role <-role-> -Scope <-scope-> details see example 4  in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-3.0.0#examples

Comment: Hi @kumar , do you have any further concerns ? If my answer solved your issue , pls kind mark this answer so that it will help others who has similar issues and I am glad to answer your further concerns in the further , thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The `New-AzADSecurityPrincipal` cmdlet has changed. Here's an updated version of the previous answer:

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal
$json = @{
  client_id = $sp.AppId
  client_secret = $sp.PasswordCredentials.SecretText
  tenant_id = (Get-AzTenant).Id
} | ConvertTo-Json
```